# Group by all categories, aggregate on a function and fill in the resulting NAs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following problem.

```
mtx =[['0','q'],
      ['0','e'],
      ['1','q'],
      ['1','w'],
      ['2','r'],
      ['2','e'],
      ['2','w'],
      ['3','t'],
      ['4','y']]
df10 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(mtx, 2, np.random.rand(len(mtx))*10, axis=1),
                    columns=['id','cat','val'])
```

I want to

1. have it grouped by **id** and **cat**,
2. have all possible **cat** present in the outcome for every **id**,
3. apply a func (say, **sum**) on **val**,
4. for absent **(id,cat)** combinations fill in 0s.

i.e. the outcome would have the following form.

```
mtx1 = [[el1, el] for el in 'qwerty' for el1 in '01234']
df11 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(mtx1, 2, '-', axis=1), 
                    columns=['id','cat','val'])
>>>
[['0' 'q' '-']
 ['1' 'q' '-']
 ['2' 'q' '-']
 ['3' 'q' '-']
 ['4' 'q' '-']
 ['0' 'w' '-']
 ['1' 'w' '-']
 ['2' 'w' '-']
 ['3' 'w' '-']
 ['4' 'w' '-']
 ['0' 'e' '-']
 ['1' 'e' '-']
 ['2' 'e' '-']
 ['3' 'e' '-']
 ['4' 'e' '-']
 ['0' 'r' '-']
 ['1' 'r' '-']
 ['2' 'r' '-']
 ['3' 'r' '-']
 ['4' 'r' '-']
 ['0' 't' '-']
 ['1' 't' '-']
 ['2' 't' '-']
 ['3' 't' '-']
 ['4' 't' '-']
 ['0' 'y' '-']
 ['1' 'y' '-']
 ['2' 'y' '-']
 ['3' 'y' '-']
 ['4' 'y' '-']]
```

For the `-` there should be the outcome of the `func` applied OR 0s.
Would it be possible to perform such an operation idiomatically in pandas? with `.groupby`? I can only think of manually creating the cross product and then checking the original `df10` if the combination exists and then applying the `func` or inserting `0` upon existence of the combination in the original `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` for `MultiIndex` `Series`, create all possible combinations by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add missing values filled by `0`, if necessary [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) and last [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
np.random.seed(2019)

mtx =[['0','q'],
      ['0','e'],
      ['1','q'],
      ['1','w'],
      ['2','r'],
      ['2','e'],
      ['2','w'],
      ['3','t'],
      ['4','y']]
df10 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(mtx, 2, np.random.rand(len(mtx))*10, axis=1),
                    columns=['id','cat','val'])
print (df10)
  id cat val
0  0   q   9
1  0   e   3
2  1   q   6
3  1   w   6
4  2   r   8
5  2   e   2
6  2   w   7
7  3   t   9
8  4   y   8
```

---

```
s = df10.groupby(['id','cat'])['val'].sum()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names)
df = s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index()
print (df.head(10))
  id cat val
0  0   e   3
1  1   e   0
2  2   e   2
3  3   e   0
4  4   e   0
5  0   q   9
6  1   q   6
7  2   q   0
8  3   q   0
9  4   q   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will help you to bring your desire results

```
mtx =[['0','q'],
      ['0','e'],
      ['1','q'],
      ['1','w'],
      ['2','r'],
      ['2','e'],
      ['2','w'],
      ['3','t'],
      ['4','y']]
df10 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(mtx, 2, np.random.rand(len(mtx))*10, axis=1),
                    columns=['id','cat','val'])
df10.pivot_table(index=['cat'], columns=['id'],values='val',aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0).stack(['id']).sort_index(level=1).reset_index()
df10.rename(columns={'cat':'cat','id':'id',0:'val'}, inplace=True)
df10
```

if you just want this data in combination format then use below code only

```
df10.pivot_table(index=['cat'], columns=['id'],values='val',aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```